# What is this old loft insulation?

Tags: insulation, attic, asbestos

Looking to insulate my house loft, there is nothing between the joists however between the battens there is this (see images) it's 10mm thick and against the hessian felt, looks extremely dated and house was build in the 1970s. Noticing some condensation between it and the felt.

Worried it might be asbestos due to the 70s build but also understand it may be glasswool.

Some insight would be great before I decide to remove it and fit new mineral wool insulation between the floor joists.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `only a lab test can confirm or deny asbestos, but that looks like thin  standard fiberglass Batt insulation.

Comment: Thank you, Would you suggest I remove this before installing my new mineral wool insulation on the floor joists level due to the condensation I've noticed?

Comment: If on/near the roof deck should be removed/moved to the floor(if decent condition).  Might also check/increase attic ventilation above floor insulation to the roof deck.  Should have outside air move from the bottom to the top of the roof.

Comment: Thank you, ventilation is somthing ill be looking at too waiting on a Endoscope and work light to check the eaves fully before installation, I'll get this old stuff removed and inspect for any condensation at night /first thing next day before I put the new mineral wool in. I'll just bin this old stuff rather than move it. Its probably from when the house was built in the 1970s.